# Is there a way for me to revert my suggested edit after it's been accepted?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I recently [suggested an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23291333) which replaced a loop initializing an array to `{1, 2, ...}` into an initialiser list. This improves the readability drastically.

The edit was approved (it is now rolled back from the owner) and everything was fine until I noticed that the problem was no longer visible.

The question was about weird behavior which no longer occurs after the edit. I am pretty sure that it just "randomly" works and remains undefined behavior though. Here a demonstration: [before](https://godbolt.org/z/0KzdmX) and [after](https://godbolt.org/z/Vs_oer).

I couldn't find an option to rollback my suggested edit and raised a flag for moderate attention instead:

> I made a suggested edit which cleaned up the code a bit. It seems this indirectly changed the output of the program (which was and is still undefined), the problematic thing is that the problem is no longer visible now. The edit was approved already and I can't see a way to undo it now.

This flag was rejected for the following reason: *"declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"*.

My edit was now rejected by the owner, which resolves the issue, but one thing is still unclear: Can I rollback / remove my own **approved** edit suggestion? Why was the flag rejected otherwise?

Comment: I guess this really drives the point about **not touching code in other user's questions**.

Comment: Your suggested edit was (fortunately) rejected, despite two robo-reviewers approving your suggestion. There is nothing to rollback?

Comment: Might be a good idea to flag for mod attention so they can have a talk with the reviewers.

Comment: Strongly suggest reading [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/8239061)

Comment: @yivi Touching code in questions is fine. You just need to get it right and not fundamentally change the question or render it incoherent through your edits. Which is *equally* necessary when editing prose.

Comment: The important thing is **don't make subjective changes to others' code**. Even if you think it's more readable and doesn't break the issue, others may think your change is *less* readable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Once you realize you've suggested an edit improperly that has been approved the only options available to you are to suggest a new edit to fix the post again, or to comment and hope that a user with 2k+ rep (or the author) will fix it for you.

If you're going to suggest an edit rolling back the change, it should have a *really* good revision comment though.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195146/discussion-on-answer-by-servy-i-suggested-an-edit-it-was-approved-how-can-i-re).